# PDO query crashing with certain input even with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a search function on my website which is hooked up with PHP PDO MySQL.

To count the results for pagination, I'm doing a query such as this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM articles WHERE (`title` LIKE ? OR MATCH(`text`) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND `active` = 1
```

However, it appears that someone is trying SQL Injection (i assume), entering in a search term like this:

> 1"'`--

Which appears to end up entirely breaking my query. It's using prepared statements as you can see with the ?'s, so I'm not sure why it's causing this error to happen:

> SQL ERROR SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
> syntax error, unexpected '-'

Doing nothing fancy, the usual PDO stuff like:

```
$this->stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
$this->stmt->execute($data_array);
```

The data is sorted by splitting it by spaces, to wrap around wildcards like this:

```
$search_array = array(explode(" ", $search_text));
$search_through = '';
$search_sql_text = '';
foreach ($search_array[0] as $item)
{
    $item = str_replace("%","\%", $item);
    $search_through .= '%'.$item.'%';
}
```

The full query basically ends up like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM articles WHERE (`title` LIKE %1"'`--% OR MATCH(`text`) AGAINST("+1"'`--" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND `active` = 1
```

What's the best way to protect against something like this?

Comment: How are you binding the parameters? Please show that important part of the php code.

Comment: Using an array put into the execute as detailed here https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: How do you know the _full query basically ends up like this_?

Comment: Also, you don't show any `%` in your parameterized query so how did they get into what you show as a result?

Comment: If PDO is able to use placeholders, as in they're not emulated, then it doesn't actually alter the query to introduce data, it sends it with placeholders and the data is shipped separately. This is a protocol-level feature of MySQL.

Comment: Have added a note about the wildcards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, it's an issue with InnoDB and any input starting with an operator even when using prepared statements it will take the string input as an operator. The easiest choice is to just strip operators, as text searching will work as normal.